# How can I get my variables to carry from dropdownlist asp.net to total and print out in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, shopping-cart

I am trying to make a shopping cart that will add the selected items from the dropdownlist with a quantity and add to cart. The user should be able to do this as many times as they want before clicking the Checkout button. By clicking the Checkout button, it will print out the quantities totaled of each item and the total of the entire purchase.

The outputs are all coming out as zero in the print line. Zero quantity and zero totalPrice. I am trying to figure out how to get the variables to carry into the print line.

Here is the ASP.net side

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MidtermExamPart1.aspx.cs" Inherits="MidtermExam.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <h3>Shopping Cart</h3><br /><br />
        <asp:Dropdownlist ID="droplist" runat="server"></asp:Dropdownlist><br />
        Quantity: <asp:TextBox ID="qty" runat="server" Width="25px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="AddToCart" runat="server" OnClick="AddToCart_Click" Text="Add to Shopping Cart" style="margin-left: 43px" Width="140px" /><br /><br /><br />

        <asp:Button ID="Checkout" runat="server" Text="Checkout" OnClick="Checkout_Click" /><br /><br />

        <asp:Label ID="message" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
    </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace MidtermExam
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                droplist.Items.Add(new ListItem("LEAN IN ($19.99)", "19.99"));
                droplist.Items.Add(new ListItem("HAPPY, HAPPY, HAPPY ($15.99)", "15.99"));
                droplist.Items.Add(new ListItem("ELEVEN RINGS ($17.99)", "17.99"));
                droplist.Items.Add(new ListItem("LET'S EXPLORE DIABETES WITH OWLS ($12.99)", "12.99"));
                droplist.Items.Add(new ListItem("THE GUNS AT LAST LIGHT ($16.99)", "16.99"));
            }
         }

        private double quantityLean;
        private double quantityHappy;
        private double quantityRings;
        private double quantityOwls;
        private double quantityGuns;
        private double totalPrice;

        protected void AddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string serviceString = droplist.SelectedItem.Text;

            double quantity = Convert.ToDouble(Request["qty"]);

            if (serviceString == "LEAN IN ($19.99)")
            {
                this.quantityLean = this.quantityLean + quantity;
                this.totalPrice = this.totalPrice + (quantity * 19.99);
            }
            if (serviceString == "HAPPY, HAPPY, HAPPY ($15.99)")
            {
                this.quantityHappy = this.quantityHappy + quantity;
                this.totalPrice = this.totalPrice + (quantity * 19.99);
            }
            if (serviceString == "ELEVEN RINGS ($17.99)")
            {
                this.quantityRings = this.quantityRings + quantity;
                this.totalPrice = this.totalPrice + (quantity * 19.99);
            }
            if (serviceString == "LET'S EXPLORE DIABETES WITH OWLS ($12.99)")
            {
                this.quantityOwls = this.quantityOwls + quantity;
                this.totalPrice = this.totalPrice + (quantity * 19.99);
            }
            if (serviceString == "THE GUNS AT LAST LIGHT ($16.99)")
            {
                this.quantityGuns = this.quantityGuns + quantity;
                this.totalPrice = this.totalPrice + (quantity * 19.99);
            }
        }

        protected void Checkout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string newMessage = String.Format("You orderered:\n\nLEAN IN ($19.99) QTY:{0}\nHAPPY, HAPPY, HAPPY ($15.99) QTY: {1}\nELEVEN RINGS ($17.99) QTY: {2}\nLET'S EXPLORE DIABETES WITH OWLS ($12.99) QTY: {3}\nTHE GUNS AT LAST LIGHT ($16.99) QTY: {4}\n\nYour total cost then would be {5:C2}", this.quantityLean, this.quantityHappy, this.quantityRings, this.quantityOwls, this.quantityGuns, this.totalPrice);
            message.Text = newMessage;
        }       
    }
}
```

I have been working on this and searching forums for hours! Please help guide me if you can

Comment: @user..what is the problem you are facing with your above code?

Comment: The outputs are all coming out as zero in the print line. Zero quantity and zero totalPrice

Comment: Did you debug it? I presume that value is not persisting in the variables you have taken. Every `postback` is through a separate object - thus, values are not persisting. Instead go for static variables or store the required data on page in some `hiddenfield` or equivalent & use the stored value on checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Just Modify your

```
string serviceString = droplist.SelectedItem.Text;
double quantity = Convert.ToDouble(qty.Text);
var Value=Convert.ToDecimal(droplist.SelectedItem.value);
```

Now use a grid to populate the summary

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name");
dt.Columns.Add("Price");
dt.Columns.Add("Quantity");
dt.Columns.Add("Total");
dt.Rows.Add(new [] {serviceString ,Value,quantity ,Value*quantity });
```

set this Table to your grids data source and for future use store it in Session (Not a Good Idea but for quick solution its Ok)

```
if(Session["List"]!=null)
dt=(DataTable)Session["List"];
```

This is basic but if you need really a good solution then I can provide something

Comment: In the line var Value=Convert.ToDecimal(droplist.SelectedItem.value); it is giving me an error that listitem does not have value

Comment: I appreciate your answer. But that's not what the OP asked.

Comment: It will convert null value to 0